# AWS User Data for Custom AMI needs credentials for root

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk, aws-sdk

I have created a custom AMI on AWS and launched an EC2 instance from this AMI. At launch, I want to pass user data (user script) to this EC2 instance but the problem is that the AMI has a password for the root user and as per my understanding every user script runs under root user.
So how should I pass password for my root user from my user script?

User script:-

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /opt/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/etc
sed -i -r '9s/127.0.0.1'/"+PublicIp+"/ xxx.properties
```

Comment: Scripts entered as user data are always executed as the root user. You do not have to provide credentials.

Comment: Hi jarmod,that's true !But the custom AMI from which EC2 is launched has a username and password. In that condition what is the workaround to execute my user data.

Comment: @PrashantRaghav this doesn't matter.  The user data script is not run from the outside, it is run from the inside.  There is a startup script that is already on every AMI, already configured to run as root, and it fetches the user data script and executes it.  **No login is needed, because nothing is logging in to your instance to run the user data script.**  You don't need a workaround for this.  If it isn't working, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!!! The thing is I have made the AMI by importing OVF template from VMWare environment.So can that be the issue(Does AWS AMI's provide some additional features to run user-data script that are not present in normal release).

Comment: What is it that your new EC2 instance can't access when using your AMI?